# Espresso Test Failed: AssertionFailedWithCause: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm new to Android Instrumentation tests. I want to check if my register activity is working correctly with Espresso.

I have tried to run it with intended and intending too. Does not seem to work.

Following is my code:

```
package com.varun.project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.support.test.espresso.intent.rule.IntentsTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Instrumentation test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<Register> ResgisterTestRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>(Register.class, true, true);

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.varun.project", appContext.getPackageName());
    }

    @Test
    public void RegisterTest(){
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.RegEmail)).perform(typeText("varunjoshi995@gmail.com"),closeSoftKeyboard());
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.RegPassword)).perform(typeText("abc123"),closeSoftKeyboard());

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.ConfirmPassword)).perform(typeText("abc123"),closeSoftKeyboard());

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.register)).perform(click());

        intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

Following is the error that I am getting:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.varun.project.MainActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:187)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:169)
at com.varun.project.ExampleInstrumentedTest.RegisterTest(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.varun.project.MainActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:87)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:282)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:190)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Answer (score -2):

As per your log your source code isn't firing any intent please debug whether the source code is firing the intent or not.

And then you can easily assert using

```
 intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));
```

Or maybe try using

```
Intents.intended(IntentMatchers.hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), SecondActivity.class)));
```

Comment: This is a solution?